# How can I add a new computed column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compute the age of a person from the data that I have:

```
Data columns in 'Person' Dataframe:
TodaysDate   non-null datetime64[ns]
YOB          non-null float64
```

So I want to make a new column inside that dataframe called 'Age' and so far I have the following code:

```
Person['Age'] = map(sum, (Person.ix[0,'TodaysDate']).year, -(Person['YOB']))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I've also tried:

```
Person['Age'] = map((Person.ix[0,'TodaysDate']).year - Person['YOB'])

TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.
```

I've tried a few different methods that were posted on other questions but none seem to work. This seems very simple to do...but can't get it to work.

Any ideas how I can use the map function to subtract the datetime column `TodaysDate` from the float column `YOB` to and put the value into `Age` column? I'd like to do this for every row in the dataframe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
    YOB
0  1955
1  1965
2  1975
3  1985
```

you don't need an extra column `TodaysDate` - you can get it dynamically:

```
In [6]: df['Age'] = pd.datetime.now().year - df.YOB

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
    YOB  Age
0  1955   62
1  1965   52
2  1975   42
3  1985   32
```

Alternatively you can use [DataFrame.eval()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
    YOB
0  1955
1  1965
2  1975
3  1985

In [17]: df.eval("Age = @pd.datetime.now().year - YOB", inplace=True)

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
    YOB  Age
0  1955   62
1  1965   52
2  1975   42
3  1985   32
```

Answer (score 11):

This answer is mostly just propaganda for [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).  I'm a fan of [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) because it returns a new `pd.DataFrame` that is a copy of the old `pd.DataFrame` with the additional columns included.  In some contexts, returning a new `pd.DataFrame` is more appropriate.  I feel that the syntax is clean and intuitive.

Also, note that I have added zero value in regards to the calculation as I've completely ripped off @MaxU's answer.

```
df.assign(Age=pd.datetime.now().year - df.YOB)

    YOB  Age
0  1955   62
1  1965   52
2  1975   42
3  1985   32
```